# Problem with multidirectional pipe (father <-> son)

Tags: c, pipe, fork

My little program includes two pipes to create a multidirectional communication between father and son.

The write on s2f [1] returns -1 but I did not understand why.

Can you help me?  Is there anything else that does not work or that I could improve?

```
/*
Write a program in C language that in sequence:
1) create 2 pipes and a child (the 2 pipes will be used for two-way communication between the parent
and son);
2) the father, after the creation of the child, takes in input from the user a file name;
3) send the child the name of the file using the first pipe;
4) make the child look for the number of spaces in the file and communicate this number to the father through the use of the second pipe;
5) let the father print the number received from son;
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f2s[2]; 
    int s2f[2];
    int fd, n;
    pid_t p;
    char buf[20];
    char c;
    int countspace=0, valueofspace;
    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        exit (-1);
    }
    if (pipe (f2s) == -1 && pipe (s2f) == -1)
        exit(-1);
    p=fork();
    if (p>0)
    {
        printf("I'm inside the father process.\n");
        close(f2s[0]);
        close(s2f[1]);
        write(f2s[1],argv[1],sizeof(argv[1]));

        read(s2f[0],&valueofspace, sizeof(int));
        printf("The spaces are %d", valueofspace);      
        printf("Father exit\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (p==0)
    {
        printf("I'm inside the child process.\n");
        close(f2s[1]);
        close(s2f[0]);
        read (f2s[0],buf,20);

        if (fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY) == -1)
            printf("Error when opening the file\n");

        while (read(fd,&c,1) > 0)
        {
            if (c==' ')
                countspace++;
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("Count: %d\n",countspace);
        n = write(s2f[1],&countspace, sizeof(countspace));
        printf("WRITE of %d BYTES\n", n);
        printf("Son exit \n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strerror(errno)` will tell you why

Comment: You probably need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the reading end of the pipe `s2f` before writing into it.

```
close(s2f[0]);
```

So there will be a `EPIPE` error when you write into the pipe. From the [online](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) reference on `write` (with added emphasis):

> The EPIPE error occurs when **fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed**. When this happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE signal. (**Thus, the write return value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal**.)

Since your program does not catch, block or ignore this signal, the write return value is not as expected and instead is -1.

Comment: But I close it in the child will not use it, he will write only. In the father it's open s2f[0] and it's close s2f[1] for the same reason. Is conceptually wrong? Thanks again

Comment: You can close it but you have to handle the SIGPIPE signal in your code. In the "father", you are not printing `n`, the value returned from the `write`.

Comment: I remove the close and the program doesn't work again.

Comment: Can you print the errno and see what is the error? Use strerror(errno)

Comment: Yes. "Bad file descriptor" on read but now "printf("WRITE of %d BYTES\n", n);" and "printf("Child exit \n");" aren't displayed.

Comment: If read of f2s[0] fails, then nothing following it will work.

Comment: You are closing f2s[0] in "father" process and attempting to read from it in "son" process. It will result in  EBADF (fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for reading).

Comment: Remove close f2s[0] in father doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are exiting only if both pipe calls fail. `if(pipe (f2s) == -1 && pipe (s2f) == -1)`. You have to exit even if one of them fails.

Comment: Right. I modify the line but now I have another problem. The program only print "I'm inside father process
I'm inside child process" and remains blocked... I don't understand anything..

Comment: Since I don't have your latest code, please read this article and you will know where you are going wrong. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html#SECTION00722000000000000000

Comment: Unfortunately no. I abandoned the exercise because I didn't find any errors.